# Java sharing same values in a class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called `Hand` and another class to test it.
`Hand` uses global variables and change their values with some methods
if in class test I create two variables of the `Hand` class
changes in one of the variables will affect the other. How can I
make them separate ?

Class `Hand`:

```
private static List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Class `Test`:

```
        Hand hand1 = new Hand();
        Hand hand2 = new Hand();
```

If I add values to `hand1` arraylist it changes also the values of `hand2` arraylist. 
Can I separate them?

Answer (score 1):

Turn the `private static List<Card>` into a `private List<Card>`.

Answer (score 1):

Make `private  List<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();` as instance variable rather then make it static..
Coz static is property of class and instance variables are property of Object... which is different for different Object ..but in case of static they are same for all objects..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` modifier which is common for all instance of the class loaded in a particular class loader.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword makes the variable class-scoped, not instance-scoped. That means the same value is common for all instances of the class. A non-static member is particular to every instance of the class. Remove the `static` keyword and you will get the desired behavior.